Error Looking for TestNG results report in workspace using pattern: **/testng-results.xml
In my project workspace, the test-results.xml file exists inside the test-output\testng-results.xml.But Jenkins fails to read the XML file and gives below error on console. In Jenkins i created the ITem with "Maven Project" ang getting this error.
enter image description here
enter image description here
I also get some solution to update "Use Custom Workspace" but there is no any textbox with the name as "Use Custom Workspace". But i also created other Item where i select "FreeStryle Project" where we have "Use Custom Workspace" textbox.

Please don't post the error text as an image: [ask]

Your setup looks for the **/testng-results.xml pattern (note the forward slash) the, but your path test-output\testng-results.xml actually uses a backslash as you seem to build your code on Windows. Try to override the pattern accordingly.

IIRC, Jenkins, via Java, will map "/" to "\" when run in Windows, so is "portable". This does not work mapping in reverse as "\" is interpreted as the escape character.
